# Chart.js Scatter plot different dot colors per data

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I am new with `Chart.js` and attempting to change the color of a dot or point when a certain value of a data is achieved. My backend program is `PHP`.  I was guessing that `color` is the correct parameter but no luck. Is this possible using `Charts.js`?

```
var scatterChartData = {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'My First dataset',
        data: [
            <?php for($x = 0; $x < $total; $x++) {?>
            {
                x: <?php round($data[$x]['PosX'],2); ?>,
                y: <?php round($data[$x]['PosY'],2); ?>,
                color: '<?php ($data[$x]['Value'] > 1)? 'red':'green' ; ?>'
            }, 
            <?php }?>  
        ]
    }]
};
```

Comment: Look at the error output  I asume you get something like `red` is not defined, you need to add quotes around strings. (`color: red`)

Comment: @RolandStarke i already updated it but still no effect.

Comment: "I was guessing" -> i checked the docs and could not find coloring the data based on the value.

Comment: @RolandStarke yes it looks like data: for Scatter only takes X,Y and R is there a way to change the color like above?